# Connecting Id's in many to many table - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I already have many Tags and I already have many Posts. I just want to post 2 Id's and insert those 2 Id's in my many to many table so the 2 records are linked.

I'm using Entity Framework and Fluent Api.

Table 1 called Tags,
Table 2 called Posts,
Table 3 called TagsPosts

My TagsPosts table has the following:

```
Tag_Id
Post_Id
```

I just want to add a new record with these 2 Ids like so:

```
var entry = new TagPost()
            {
                Tag_Id = tagId,
                Post_Id = postId
            };

ApplicationDbContext.TagsPosts.Add(entry);
```

In my context I have:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<TagPost> TagsPosts { get; set; }
}
```

My fluent API relationship:

```
ToTable("Tags");
HasKey(t => t.Id);
HasMany(t => t.Posts).WithMany(p => p.Tags);
```

The issue is i'm getting the error when I try and add the migration using code first:

```
EntityType 'TagPost' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
TagsPosts: EntityType: EntitySet 'TagsPosts' is based on type 'TagPost' that has no keys defined.
```

This is what TagPost looks like:

```
public class TagPost
{
    public int Tag_Id { get; set; }
    public int Post_Id { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include your TagPost class if you map this M2M relationship by convention.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
    .ToTable("Tags")    
    .HasKey(t => t.Id)
    .HasMany(t => t.Posts)
    .WithMany(p => p.Tags)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
       cs.MapLeftKey("Tag_Id");
       cs.MapRightKey("Post_Id");
       cs.ToTable("TagPost");
    });
```

Read this for further info: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

EDIT:

```
//get post object from context
var post = context.Posts.Find(postId);
//get tag object from context
var tag = context.Tags.Find(tagId);
//associate objects
post.Tags.Add(tag);
//commit to db
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. That looks good but how do i add the entry to the database without the TagPost class? Do I need to include it in my DbContext?

Comment: Simply use `tag.Posts.Add(post)` and save your context. EF will already know to use the TagPost table behind the scenes.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but could you provide an example of what the repository would look like based on what i had above? Also, I'm not adding a post, just adding the Id's to link the 2 records that already exist in the database together, arn't I?

Comment: @DBoi i've added an example to the answer